# Using opencv-python on windows 10, python 3.6 and anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

After having try many times and after searching a lot, I still don't manage to use opencv-python. Actually, `import cv2` works for me, but when I want to make this [file](https://github.com/arunponnusamy/object-detection-opencv/blob/master/yolo_opencv.py) working, I got this message

> Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed

Do you have an idea of what is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, OpenCV images are using the same data representation as Numpy arrays. It's quite frequent to use numpy logic on OpenCV images and vice versa.

So first thing to check is that you have numpy installed.

Assuming you have numpy installed, maybe you mixed `pip` and `conda` commands to install opencv and numpy ? It's generally something to avoid unless you really  know what you are doing.

You can run `pip list` and `conda list` to have a quick overview of installed packages.

Using pip only is good enough in most cases, a lot of prebuild python wheels for Windows are available on pip, including opencv-python and numpy.

After cleaning conda installed packages, try to run : 
`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy` to make a clean numpy install.